# Procedure or function Event_Update has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql, procedure

I am getting an error message `Procedure or function Event_Update has too many arguments specified.` while trying to update table event with procedure function from c# code

**procedure for update**

```
create procedure Event_Update
@id int,
@image varchar(50),
@title varchar(255),
@description varchar(255),
@date date

as

begin
update event set image = @image,title=@title,description=@description,event_date=@date where id=@id
end
```

**Event Table**

```
create table event(
id int identity(1,1) primary key,
image varchar(50) not null,
title varchar(255) not null,
description varchar(255) not null,
event_date date not null
)
```

**C# code**

```
public void update(int id,string title, string image, string events, string date)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "Event_Update";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", image);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", events);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Don't reuse command objects.  Create a new one for each query you want to execute.  Also don't reuse connections objects.  The DB connection pool will handle that for you, so just create a connection for the scope of one transaction and put both in a `using` statement so they get disposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd` is global variable? clear `cmd.Parameters` in `update` method:

```
public void update(int id,string title, string image, string events, string date)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "Event_Update";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", image);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", events);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```